# Укажите наречия, исторически образованные от глагольных корней

Tags: словообразование, глаголы, наречия, морфемный-разбор

Укажите наречия, исторически образованные от глагольных корней из предложенных: только, пусто, всегда, мимо, пешком.

Answer (score 1):

Если только мимо-от "минуть", пройти стороной

Пусто-пустить - однокоренные, но наречие образовано от прилагательного пустой, а не от пустить, вот "пустить" - от пустой, это да.

Comment: Т.е. получается только одно слово "мимо" ? А остальные, точно нет?

Comment: Не знаю, может, они имели в виду и "пусто"-"пустить", остальные точно не от глагола